# .format placeholders and .CSV fields

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There are two .format placeholders in the variable. One between `<Address1>{0}</Address1>`
one between `<City>{1}</City>`

```
string = '''
         https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="564WILLC0589">
         <Address><Address1>{0}</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>{1}</City>
         <State>IL</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>

        '''.format("","")
```

I have a .CSV file with two columns and five rows, for example:

[image]

How can I insert "Address1" field in placeholder `{0}` and "City" field in placeholder `{1}` of this variable, which is an URL, so that I end up with five URLs?

Here's what I have, but it places the whole column in its respective placeholder.

```
import pandas as pd

col_list = ["Address1", "City"]
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jpilbeam\USPSAPIWCHDUpdateAll.csv', usecols=col_list)

string = '''
         https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="564WILLC0589">
         <Address><Address1>{0}</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>{1}</City>
         <State>IL</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>

        '''.format(df["Address1"],df["City"])
print(string)
```

**EDIT:** Here's a [link](https://webapp.willcountyillinois.com/Requests/USPSAPIWCHDUpdateAll.csv) to my .CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f-strings` if you are using python 3.6 or greater with list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': ['1234 address', '1235 address', '1236 address'],
                   'city': ['Auora']*3})
l = [
f'https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="564WILLC0589"><Address><Address1>{a}</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>{c}</City><State>IL</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>' for a,c in list(zip(df['address'], df['city']))
]

['https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="564WILLC0589"><Address><Address1>1234 address</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>Auora</City><State>IL</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>',
 'https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="564WILLC0589"><Address><Address1>1235 address</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>Auora</City><State>IL</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>',
 'https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="564WILLC0589"><Address><Address1>1236 address</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>Auora</City><State>IL</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>']
```

Comment: it works the same way. Read your csv file into memory using `Thanks, I wasn't aware of f-string! I'm using Python 3.6.9. I see you created a dataframe as an example. But, I'm trying to read a file into the l variable with df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jpilbeam\USPSAPIWCHDUpdateAll.csv')` then use the list comprehension to create a list of strings.

Comment: OK, thanks. I read it into memory ```df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jpilbeam\USPSAPIWCHDUpdateAll.csv')```. Then I used your sytax: ```l='https...<Address1>{a}</Address1>...<City>{c}</City>...'for a,c in list(zip(df['Address1'], df['City']))]```.
No errors, but it printed the strings like ```...<Address1>{a}</Address1>...<City>{c}</City>...```. It didn't use the fields from the .CSV?

Comment: that is all you need to do

Comment: No errors, but it printed the strings like ```...<Address1>{a}</Address1>...<City>{c}</City>....``` It didn't use the fields from the .CSV?

Comment: Make sure the `f` is before the start of the string